# How many physically demonstrated universal scalar fields exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Besides Higgs' field, and not counting purely theoretical universal scalar fields such as those attributed to branes, how many universal scalar fields have been demonstrated? Please include names of such fields, if they exist.

Comment: If you only count possibly fundamental fields, it is just the Higgs. That's a big part of why it's so important -- it's the _first_ scalar field we've found.

Comment: Nothing beyond the Standard Model has been experimentally observed, and the Higgs is the only scalar in the standard model. So, for now it's just the Higgs.

Comment: What is a "universal" field? If you ask for scalar fields: pions are excitations of scalar fields.

Comment: @LorentzMayer to nitpick just a bit, pions are pseudoscalars, not scalars, but, of course, there are scads of scalar mesons as well; either will obey the K-G equation  that seems to intrigue the OP, albeit without clear justification. Elementary vs composite distinctions may well be  an arrogant affectation of somebody's confidence that Higgs substructure would not be observable in their lifetime...

Comment: @Lorenz Mayer - 'Universal Field' is everywhere, every-when, at every scale, continuous through that range of parameters.

Answer (score -1):

There's just the Higgs field.

The Klein-Gordon equation is a classical scalar field that's used to teach quantisation of classical fields but there is no such physical field. In fact, Schrodinger found this equation before his eponymous equation but discarded it because of its unphysical properties.

Comment: Isn't the Higgs field described by the Klein-Gordon equation?

Comment: The Klein-Gordon equation has unphysical properties *if you treat it as an equation for the wavefunction of a single particle.* But properly understood as an equation for a scalar field, there is nothing unphysical about it.